# Nexus 5, I'm getting remote: flash write failure while trying to fix a bootloop

Tags: nexus-5, boot-loop

Before I say anything I just want to say I didn't install any custom ROMs nor rooted my phone.

I've downloaded the factory images from here https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#hammerhead

I put my phone into bootloader and I start the flash-all.bat script from the folder I've downloaded above. It runs this script:

```
PATH=%PATH%;"%SYSTEMROOT%\System32"
fastboot flash bootloader bootloader-hammerhead-hhz12d.img
fastboot reboot-bootloader
ping -n 5 127.0.0.1 >nul
fastboot flash radio radio-hammerhead-m8974a-2.0.50.2.22.img
fastboot reboot-bootloader
ping -n 5 127.0.0.1 >nul
fastboot -w update image-hammerhead-lrx22c.zip

echo Press any key to exit...
pause >nul
exit
```

I get the following output:

```
OKAY [  0.307s]
writing 'bootloader'...
**FAILED (remote: not supported in locked device)**
finished. total time: 0.407s
rebooting into bootloader...
OKAY [  0.050s]
finished. total time: 0.050s
< waiting for device >
target reported max download size of 1073741824 bytes
sending 'radio' (45521 KB)...
OKAY [  1.732s]
writing 'radio'...
**FAILED (remote: not supported in locked device)**
finished. total time: 1.842s
rebooting into bootloader...
OKAY [  0.046s]
finished. total time: 0.046s
< waiting for device >
target reported max download size of 1073741824 bytes
archive does not contain 'boot.sig'
archive does not contain 'recovery.sig'
failed to allocate 1005027540 bytes
error: update package missing system.img
Press any key to exit...
```

I've noticed the bolded lines so I unlocked the phone using a command *fastboot oem unlock*. It unlocks it, however if I reset the phone, it's locked again. People on the Internet say that if this happens then the phone is dead. I hope it's not the case.

I've tried running the script again when the phone is unlocked:

```
target reported max download size of 1073741824 bytes
sending 'bootloader' (2579 KB)...
OKAY [  0.202s]
writing 'bootloader'...
**FAILED (remote: flash write failure)**
finished. total time: 0.402s
rebooting into bootloader...
OKAY [  0.090s]
finished. total time: 0.090s
< waiting for device >
target reported max download size of 1073741824 bytes
sending 'radio' (45521 KB)...
OKAY [  1.709s]
writing 'radio'...
**FAILED (remote: flash write failure)**
finished. total time: 2.939s
rebooting into bootloader...
OKAY [  0.100s]
finished. total time: 0.100s
< waiting for device >
target reported max download size of 1073741824 bytes
archive does not contain 'boot.sig'
archive does not contain 'recovery.sig'
failed to allocate 1005027540 bytes
error: update package missing system.img
Press any key to exit...
```

As you can see I get the FAILURE (remote: flash write failure).

I've tried removing the commands that reset the phone so the phone stays locked and I get this output after running the modified script:

```
target reported max download size of 1073741824 bytes
sending 'bootloader' (2579 KB)...
OKAY [  0.300s]
writing 'bootloader'...
**FAILED (remote: flash write failure)**
finished. total time: 0.492s
target reported max download size of 1073741824 bytes
sending 'radio' (45521 KB)...
OKAY [  1.716s]
writing 'radio'...
**FAILED (remote: flash write failure)**
finished. total time: 1.894s
target reported max download size of 1073741824 bytes
archive does not contain 'boot.sig'
archive does not contain 'recovery.sig'
failed to allocate 1005027540 bytes
**error: update package missing system.img**
Press any key to exit...
```

Again, the FAILURE (remote: flash write failure) occurs but I don't understand why it can't find "system.img" because it is in the folder where the script is.

I've also tried the tutorial from this Youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pJnoiMTw5cY

When I try the first command which is "fastboot flash system system.img" I get the same error.

So, is my phone dead or can I still fix it?

EDIT: I've RMA-ed[1] the phone and they've sent me a replacement. I hope this thread will help future people.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_merchandise_authorization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this [thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/help/getting-failure-remote-flash-write-t3030972/post58850140#post58850140) they told me my emmc is fried because I can't lock / unlock my phone so I [RMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_merchandise_authorization)-ed it.

Answer (score 4):

The flash-all.sh script does not take into consideration that your bootloader is locked after each restart.

I opened the shell script and executed each command one by one, re-unlocking with the following after each command:

```
fastboot oem unlock
```

I flashed each image with no errors, but it did not seem to write to memory regardless.

Comment: I get `FAILED (remote: Already Unlocked)` even tough it is freshly rebooted.

Comment: Be careful. Unlocking bootloader will delete all personal data.

Answer (score 0):

The interesting point is: Although you don't get these "only allowed in unlocked state" warnings anymore, is your bootloader really unlocked? What output do you get when you run the following command in unlocked mode?:

`fastboot oem device-info`

And: Can you still boot into recovery?

Comment: C:\Users\Neven\Desktop\hammerhead-5.1>
...
(bootloader)    Device tampered: true
(bootloader)    Device unlocked: true
(bootloader)    off-mode-charge: true
OKAY [ -0.000s]
finished. total time: -0.000s

I can boot into recovery mode. The little android with an exclamation mark inside a red triangle shows up. I tried wiping the cache and factory resets but as far as I've understood it failed. I can't photograph the screen at the moment. What's also interesting is that I don't have "wipe Davik-cache" command but I've heard I should have that.

Comment: Maybe try booting from fastboot into a custom recovery with 'fastboot boot recovery your-recovery.img' From there, You could try to flash the system partition from a ZIP file, but the behavior you describe is very unlikely and it seems like you cannot write anything to your mmc-device (the flash chip), since even wiping cache seems to fail. Would be interesting though to see if you can mount partitions r/w in custom recovery and modify their content from there. And since you said you didnt do anything with custom roms, how did you get the bootloop problem in the first place?

Comment: @kulesdzl I tried the first command but got this error 
C:\Users\Neven\Desktop\hammerhead-5.1>fastboot boot recovery recovery.img
cannot load 'recovery': No such file or directory

Comment: Of course you have to load a proper recovery.img before attempting this. I recommend using a recovery from the twrp project, you can get images here: http://techerrata.com/browse/twrp2/hammerhead

Comment: I've downloaded images from https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#hammerhead I have a recovery.img so I don't know why it says it can't find it. I don't know what caused the boot loop. I didn't install custom ROMs nor rooted my phone. The last thing I remember what happened is that my phone started lagging and I was getting app.google.etc. stopped working. Don't remember the exact error. So I googled and people said to wipe the cache of google's applications. So I did and the phone started working again. The phone restarted itself somehow in my pocket and entered bootloop later.

Comment: Well, this is the stock recovery which will not allow you to do quite much, and you will not be able to connect via adb to it. Therefore, try booting a custom recovery to be able to get an idea what is going on from the command shell.

Answer (score 0):

Wipe cache from recovery, make sure you have latest adb and fastboot files.
In the recovery menu, execute these commands.

```
adb shell
recovery --wipe_data
recovery --wipe_data
```

The supplied commands :

```
 *   --wipe_data - erase user data (and cache), then reboot
 *   --wipe_cache - wipe cache (but not user data), then reboot
```

Use [Nexus Root Toolkit](http://www.wugfresh.com/nrt/) to do the job done : http://www.wugfresh.com/nrt/
[image: wugfresh's nexus root toolkit]

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can get into adb from an unwriteable emmc:

1. Download twrp, extract it so you see `recovery.img`.
2. Unlock using `fastboot oem unlock`.  do not reboot.
3. Boot into the custom recovery (not flash) using `fastboot boot recovery.img`.

You will now be rebooted in twrp, from where you can access `adb` and `adb shell`.

Comment: I have the same issue and haven't been able to find the recovery.img file inside any of the twrp images. I feel like I am doing something wrong or am looking at the wrong img files maybe. Is there a link to where I can get the correct TWRP? Thanks!!